# Why do not constructive questions appear on the FAQ tab?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions, not-constructive, frequent-tab

Why do some questions which have been closed as not constructive appear on the FAQ tab?

For example, when I choose the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag and then choose the 'FAQ' tab, I see [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android) appear within the list.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKtlO.png]

Comment: ..and for [android] and [pdf] it's even second place.

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense. Yeah, good question

Comment: If you hover over the "faq" tab with your mouse it states "questions with the most links". I would assume this is the simple criterion by which this is judged and closed questions are not explicitly excluded. (Though I don't know anything about the actual implementation of this). And that said, closed questions are not necessarily void of information. They might well hold interesting material.

Comment: I'm only speculating, but I think they're allowed to appear there so they don't get asked again (and again and again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many closed  as not constructive questions are closed   just because it isn't the domain of SO as Q&A site.

> this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or
>   extended discussion

However they may be useful for many users, and can be asked by many users, i.e. FAQ.
As it was noted in a  A_funs
[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1884724)

> Why do all the threads labeled "not constructive" have the most up
>   votes?

IMO it's a good thing, that high-voted questions appears in a FAQ even if they are closed as "non-constructive". Frankly speaking, when I am searching for an answer for my question, I don't care is it in domain of SO or not, I just want to find a reference to the info that many people already considered useful.