# How can we search inside the "faq tab"?

Tags: support, search, sorting, frequent-tab

After many Stack months, I first clicked on the `faq tab`.

[image: faq tab in questions page]

*Sidenote: at first, it was not clear what's its function (just the hover tells it, right?), and I just got it after searching this Meta.*

- [Faq question tab is incorrectly named](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95786/185667)
- [Why do not constructive questions appear on the FAQ tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156129/185667)

I can't get any hint from the [Search Options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search).
Is it possible to search items within a Tag ordered by "Most linked"? <sup>(or some combination of that)</sup>

Comment: "...it is not clear what it does (just the hover tells it, right?), ..." I found the tooltip "questions with the most links" quite informative.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby, I think I didn't express it properly, rephrased that part. [update] I click too fast and normally don't see tooltips :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible.

When performing a search, you have four sort options for the search results:

1. Relevance: sort by relevancy of the search term e.g. where it appears most times.
2. Newest: sort by the date where the question was posted.
3. Votes: sort by number of votes. (Think it should be *score* but not sure at the moment)
4. Active: sort by activity date i.e. date of last activity in the question.

What you ask for is to add fifth sort option by popularity or amount of links, which is currently not available for search results.

As for the faq tab of the per site Questions page, the site simply "remembers" the last tab you visited and when browsing questions of specific tag it will still be under that tab. This is *not* a search, this is the whole questions list sorted by specific criteria.